# Error executing view with massive UNIONs

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have to execute a view **A** that takes data from other view **B** composed by the UNION of three hundred views of the same type (a join between two tables). When I execute the view **A**, it crashes showing this error:

> Error: “The query processor ran out of internal resources and could
>   not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.”

As there is an error, the query execution plan is not generated but I have been able to generate it for another execution. I have not been able to upload view the Execution plan for **A** because it weights to much but you can see the execution plan for **B** here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1i7FiTWb

[image]

Is there some way to avoid this error?

Comment: You have performance timebomb on your hands because you are using nested views. And by the sounds of it they are getting nested multiple layers deep. This is a sure fire way to totally destroy the optimizer ability to generate a decent execution plan. And seriously....300 views???? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: Yes, the query has several nested levels and in some weird but possible scenarios it can has 300 views.

Comment: As I said nested views are killing you here. But there seems to be some other serious architecture issue if you have a query with as many as 300 views.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the views are in several databases and I got no way to reference dinamically objects from other databases.

Comment: _I got no way to reference dinamically objects from other databases_ Why?

Comment: Voting to close as the only way to solve this question is by not doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You HAVE to rework your architecture. Sql Server has limited resources and selecting from 300 views is an utterly ridiculous amount.

There are no ifs, buts or maybes, such a configuration will continue to plague you until you have and no-one here will be able to help you.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have created that configuration and my goal is not to redefine it.

Comment: Well that's a problem then they no one else but you can solve. No one here will be able to help you given that the issue is your architecture. As such this is not a question that fits in with Stack Overflows philosophy.